# Android. Add and read to database?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I'm new to development!
I have a text list of exercises and I want to make this list appear in my application.
There is an idea to use SQLite (Room).

Question:

1. How can I add my list to the database?

Perhaps there are other options for implementation?

Comment: Room [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin) and [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) would be a good place to start learning about Room.

Comment: But how can I correctly add to the database myself, what do I need and read?

Comment: That's why I have added links to the resources. Go through them.